# Java: How to blink trayicon when receiving notifications?

Tags: java, trayicon

Need to blink the tray icon upon receiving notification. For this I have two images. I am using `Thread` `runnable()` and with certain interval making the thread sleep, add and remove images. This is working fine but when blinking all other tray icons present in task bar are also blinking. Not sure whether this is a good approach.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {

            for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
                remove(Image2);
                add(Image1)
                long intratime=1001*1l;
                Thread.sleep(intratime);
                remove(Image1);
                add(Image2);
                long intertime=1001*1l;
                Thread.sleep(intertime);
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
}}).start();
```

Comment: Are you talking about the MS Windows task bar tray icons? Could you post your code here so that we can help you?

Comment: It's not really a good approach because the operating system needs to re-evaluate the taskbar content once when you remove it and once when you add it back, which is probably where the blinking happens. You should alternate the content of the image rather than deleting and re-adding it, which will probably achieve the same effect.

Comment: Yes, I have added the trayicon on system tray bar, I just need to blink the icon just like messenger which blinks when there is new message

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you implemented this by `Thread runnable()`.
You can use [TrayIcon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/TrayIcon.html) to create a tray icon. To add pop up, you can use the method [setPopupMenu(PopupMenu popup)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/TrayIcon.html#setPopupMenu(java.awt.PopupMenu)) function.

Answer (score 0):

Simple replace the image of the [TrayIcon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/TrayIcon.html) with a blank icon or different coloured icon

Answer (score 0):

You should not remove an add the complete `TrayIcon` but rather replace the `TrayIcon`'s image, e.g. like this:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(Image1);
            SystemTray.getSystemTray().add(trayIcon);
            long intratime=1001*1l;
            for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
                Thread.sleep(intratime);
                trayIcon.setImage(Image2);
                Thread.sleep(intratime);
                trayIcon.setImage(Image1);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
}}).start();
```

Reason: Each time when you are add or remove a trayicon from the systemtray, the OS might rearrange a other currently displayed icons. But when you just replace the icon image, then no rearrangement will occour.